# Canceling/Stopping a callback function from executing in jQuery/Javascript

Tags: jquery, callback, jquery-animate

I have an animation that is set to play after a timeout. This animation repeats itself over on different elements after it completes. I'm utilizing the `animate` method's callback function to initiate the next animation. My extracted code looks like:

```
function fancyAnimation() {
    // Get a random object property, which is actually the id for a dot
    var id = getRandomNumber( 1, 100 );

    // Apply an effect to the dot
    $( '#test' + id ).effect(
        'pulsate',
        { times : 3 },
        1000,
        fancyAnimation
    );
}
```

On a click event, I want the animations to stop. At any given time, the "fancyAnimation" function is queued to run, which just queues it again and again and so forth.

Is there a way that I can stop this function from executing, thereby ending the infinite loop on a certain event? If so, how would you do this?

Thank you so much!

EDIT: By request, the code that initiates `fancyAnimation`.

```
function initiateFancyAnimation() {
    animation_timeout = setTimeout( "fancyAnimation()", animation_interval );
}
```

Comment: Show us the code that calls `fancyAnimation()`.

Comment: @MattBall - the initiating code is there. It shouldn't matter in this case; however, as I'm just looking for a way to stop `fancyAnimation` after it's been queued. I'm not sure it's possible without a refactor.

Comment: A control statement (if) within fancyanimation() before calling a new recursion would do the trick. For example: a boolean variable which is set true by a timeout event and false by a click event. Posting as a comment because I'm unaware if this is possible in JavaScript.

Comment: Yeah...that's how I have it set up currently (not in the extracted code that I showed), but it just doesn't feel right to me. It's interesting that the three answers I've received so far pretty much suggest that same thing. I'm just looking for information about whether what I want to do is possible or not, and by that, I mean, is it possible to stop execution of a function that is queued to run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the easy way would be to set a global flag that you check each time the function runs:

```
var runAnimation;

function fancyAnimation() {
    if (runAnimation) {
        // your function body as written
    }
}

$('#start').click(function() {
    runAnimation = true;
    fancyAnimation();
});

$('#stop').click(function() {
    runAnimation = false;
});
```

Comment: Well, this validates my approach ;) This is exactly what I did, but for some reason it just feels oh so wrong, so I was looking for another approach. Is there a hard way, but perhaps better way?

Comment: Not really :). The only way I know of to truly cancel a callback is to reassign the function to a no-op, e.g. `fancyAnimation = $.noop`. But that prevents you from running it again, unless you have a reference somewhere else - I don't see it being a good option in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You could apply a certain class to the 'dot' when the user clicks the item and then check for that class on each loop like this:

```
$('#button').click(function(){
    $('#targetDot').addClass('stop');
});

function fancyAnimation() {    
// Get a random object property, which is actually the id for a dot
    var id = getRandomNumber( 1, 100 );

    // Check for Class and Execute ONLY is .stop is not found //
    if ($(id).hasClass('stop') !== true ){
        // Apply an effect to the dot
        $( '#test' + id ).effect(
            'pulsate',
            { times : 3 },
            1000,
            fancyAnimation
        );
    }
}
```

EDIT:

An alternative that I've used in the past is a plugin called [$.doTimeout](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-dotimeout-plugin/) which allows for the callback to be controlled a little better.

With this plugin you could do something like this:

```
$.doTimeout('timeoutID', 3000, function() {
    // Check for Global Run True / False Flag //
    if (runAnimation){
        fancyAnimation();
    }
});
```

Not sure if this helps as the callback is still run; however it would allow you to pause the actual animation function from running.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! That's a clever method. Unfortunately, I am looking for any information about being able to stop that function from executing. I'm thinking that it's not possible, but thought I would at least ask.

Answer (score 0):

Now that functional reactive programming has arrived, here's one way to do it in this style using [BaconJS](http://baconjs.github.io/api.html#bus) (though it's not any shorter).

```
$('#start').click(function(){  
    // open event bus
    var eventBus = new Bacon.Bus();

    // tell eventBus to run animation every time it receives event
    eventBus.onValue(function(){
        fancyAnimation();
    });

    // push initial event to start animation immediately
    eventBus.push();

    // continue to push events at interval
    eventBus.plug(Bacon.fromPoll(animation_interval, function(){
        return new Bacon.Next();
    }));

    $("#start").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    $("#stop").removeAttr("disabled"); 

    // tell eventBus to end when stop is clicked
    $('#stop').click(function(){
        eventBus.end();

        $("#stop").attr("disabled", "disabled");
        $("#start").removeAttr("disabled");   
    });
});
```

Working demo at http://jsfiddle.net/ronaldchanou/o4hk0176/2/